# Is there a way to claim a car purchase in the tax return?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, car, purchase

I purchased a car for $19K; $6K was paid upfront, and the rest is financed over 3 years. Is there a way I can deduct the car purchase in certain circumstances? This vehicle is primarily used for work. I am in the U.S. and work as a consultant to a company.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[IRS Publication 463](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p463.pdf) is a great resource to help you understand what you can and can't deduct.

It's not a yes/no question, it depends on the exact company use, other use, and contemporaneous record keeping.

Comment: Contemporaneous record keeping is also essential if you want to write off any miles as community service.

Comment: Deducting miles as part of your itemized medical expenses too.

Answer (score 4):

You've got two options.

1. Deduct the business portion of the depreciation and actual expenses for operating the car.
2. Use the IRS standard mileage rate of $.575/mile in 2015. Multiply your business miles by the rate to calculate your deduction.

Assuming you're a sole proprietor you'll include a Schedule C to your return and claim the deduction on that form.